# Is vmware virtualization faster on same SSD as the images or on separate SSD?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmware-player

I use VMware player with two SSDs, main windows 10 OS on first SSD, I will store the linux virtual images on second SSD ...

Will the virtual machines run faster if the VMware player program is installed on same SSD as the main OS or on the same drive as the virtual images ?

Comment: I see it received downvote(s) and close request(*), if you can clarify in a comment it would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All ok.If windows10 and vmware installed together may be unloading problems.However,this situation is very small,so do not worry.